# Better syntax highlighting for Java in Vim?

Tags: vim, java, sublime-text-2, syntax-highlighting

I've found Vim to have fantastic syntax highlighting with my preferred color schemes for Ruby and Python, but whenever I need to write Java code, it's like I haven't even turned on highlighting in the first place.

[image]

As you can see, keywords are highlighted, but there's no highlighting for parentheses or methods. In Sublime Text (a far less preferred editor by me), I see far better highlighting. There is italicization for class names and highlighting for mathematical operators. Vim looks sparse in comparison.

[image]

Is there any way, any way at all to get that luscious Sublime Text-style highlighting on Vim?

Comment: Have you tried using [Vintage mode](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html) in Sublime Text? It changes all the key bindings to those vi(m) uses, yet still allows for powerful features of ST2 like better syntax highlighting and multiple selection editing.

Comment: I do have Vintage Mode enabled in ST2, but I still prefer Vim because I can use it in the terminal, with several tmux panes open so that I can ssh into my remote machine simultaneously without leaving my editor for more than a second.

Comment: yes, there is that minor setback of using a GUI editor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [cSyntaxAfter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3265) plugin. It highlights operators et cetera.

Another option is to edit the `syntax/java.vim` script and add highlighting for the `Operator` group. Have a look at `syntax/pascal.vim` as an example.

It you want to use italics for class names, that should be possible if the java syntax file recognizes them as a group, and I think it does. It seems that class names are in the `JavaTypedef` group.

You would then have to define a new highlight for that group. That would mean removing the line

```
JavaHiLink javaTypedef                Typedef
```

from the syntax file, and adding a new one. Below I'm re-using the hightlight declaration for Type, which is what Typedef is linked to. I changed the `term` from `underline` to `italic`.

You should put the following in yout `java.vim` syntax file.

```
hi javaTypedef term=italic cterm=NONE ctermfg=LightGreen ctermbg=NONE gui=bold guifg=#60ff60 guibg=NONE
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but is/are there any plugin or plugins to capitalize class names?

Comment: @kunaicode: Not that I know of. Syntax highlighting doesn't alter the _meaning_ of the code. Capitalization does. Personally I'd _immediately_ remove a plugin that would automatically change code that I have written.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion-- I meant, _italicize_ class names. Not capitalize. Sorry.

Comment: @kunaicode: See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there simply isn't a rich syntax file out there.

But we can squeeze a little bit more out of the bundled syntax file we have:

```
let java_highlight_functions = 1
let java_highlight_all = 1
" If you are trying this at runtime, you need to reload the syntax file
set filetype=java

" Some more highlights, in addition to those suggested by cmcginty
highlight link javaScopeDecl Statement
highlight link javaType Type
highlight link javaDocTags PreProc
```

The first trick came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32974905/99777).

If someone ever makes a richer Java syntax file, we should add it to [vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/issues/129)!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using base16-default color scheme in Vim and for some reason it does a bad job defining colors for Java. Adding the following lines will help get part of the way there:

```
" Java: 'new', 'instanceof'
highlight Operator ctermfg=5  guifg=#d175bc
" Java: 'this', 'super'
highlight Typedef ctermfg=5  guifg=#d175bc
" Java: 'void', 'int', 'double'
highlight Type ctermfg=4  guifg=#69b7d3
" literal numbers
highlight Number term=bold ctermfg=16 gui=bold guifg=#d2d22d
```